# FileNotFoundException on FileOutputStream

Tags: java, android

My android application is very simply extract zip.

I want to create a folder with the FileName erase the extension (.zip) in the zip file.

And i'm succeeded.

However, the exception in some devices.

device name : KM-S300
os version : 2.3.4

source:

```
private void extractZip (File file) throws UTFDataFormatException {
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    ZipInputStream zis = null;
    ZipEntry ze = null;

    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    int offset = 0;

    String rootName = file.getAbsolutePath();
    rootName = rootName.substring(0, rootName.lastIndexOf("."));

    String rootFileName = rootName.substring(rootName.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

    File root = new File(rootName);
    root.mkdirs();

    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        zis = new ZipInputStream(fis);

        while (( ze = zis.getNextEntry() ) != null) {
            try {
                File f = new File(root, ze.getName());
                if (!f.isDirectory()) {
                    f.getParentFile().mkdirs();

                    fos = new FileOutputStream(f); // <<-- ERROR
                    while (( offset = zis.read(data) ) != -1) {
                        fos.write(data, 0, offset);
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                try {
                    fos.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {}
            }
        }

        file.delete();

    }catch (UTFDataFormatException e){
        throw e;
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            zis.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {}
        try {
            fis.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

I can't understand Exception

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/test/marker/Explosion/failed/0.png (No such file or directory)
    at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(Native Method)
    at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedFileSystem.open(BlockGuard.java:232)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:94)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:66)
    at com.sample.MainActivity.extractZip(MainActivity.java:507)
```

Made to the parent folder of the File prior to creating the FileOutputStream

Why did exception by application?

Answer (score 0):

You're only creating the parent directory if the new file doesn't exist or isn't a directory. It's not a sensible test. You should create it if the *parent directory* doesn't exist.

Comment: Is it FileNotFoundException relevant?? mkdirs is added temporarily because of Exception. But the problem continues. T_T